# Retreiving data- attributes in jquery- error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have javascript code which dynamically generates and outputs a button:

```
temphtml = temphtml + `
<div class="card border-secondary mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title DataName">` + Name + ` </h5>
        <h5 class="card-title DataAge">` +  Age + `yrs </h5>
        <h5 class="card-title DataGender">` + Gender + `</h5>
        <p class="card-text DataHospitalID">Hospital ID:`+ HospitalID + `</p>
        <p class="card-text DataMobile">Mobile:`+ Mobile + `</p>
        <p class="card-text DataAddress"><small class="text-muted">` + Address + `</p>
        <a href="#" id="checkinbtn`+i+`" class="btn btn-primary checkinbtn" data-options='{
            Name:"` + Name + `",
            Age:"` + Age + `",
            Gender:"` + Gender + `",
            HospitalID:"` + HospitalID + `",
            Mobile:"` + Mobile + `",
            Address:"` + Address + `"}'>Check in</a>
        </div>
  </div>        `;
```

The html code output looks like this:

```
<a href="#" id="checkinbtn0" class="btn btn-primary checkinbtn" data-options="{
Name:&quot;First Last&quot;,
Age:&quot;28&quot;,
Gender:&quot;Female&quot;,
HospitalID:&quot;3&quot;,
Mobile:&quot;9000000000&quot;,
Address:&quot;Somewhere&quot;}">Check in</a>
```

I am trying to retrieve one of the options:

`$("#checkinbtn0").data( "options" )` gives:

```
"{
Name:\"First Last\",
Age:\"28\",
Gender:\"Female\",
HospitalID:\"3\",
Mobile:\"9000000000\",
Address:\"Somewhere\"}"
```

And `$("#checkinbtn0").data( "options" ).Name` gives undefined.
Is it a problem with escaping special characters? How can I retrieve a value like the Name field?

Comment: Have you tried to `JSON.parse($("#checkinbtn0").data( "options" ))` ?

Comment: Your data/otions contains a String which you need to convert to an Object first to be able to access its properties. Use `JSON.parse($("#checkinbtn0").data("options")).Name`

Comment: @connexo That gives me `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 2 column 6 of the JSON data`

Comment: `data-options=\`{"Name":"${Name}","Age":"${Age}","Gender":"${Gender}","HospitalID":"${HospitalID}","Mobile":"${Mobile}","Address":"${Address}"}\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a problem with escaping special characters?

Kinda yes. No need to escape like that, just write your string as below, then convert `string` to `object` with `$.parseJSON`:

```js
var Name = 'Alex';
var Age, Gender, HospitalID, Mobile, Address;

var temphtml = $('<a href="#" id="checkinbtn0" class="btn btn-primary checkinbtn">Check in</a>').attr({
  'data-option': '{"Name": "' + Name + '","Age":  "' + Age + '","Gender":  "' + Gender + '","HospitalID":  "' + HospitalID + '","Mobile": "' + Mobile + '","Address": "' + Address + '"  }'
});

$('#target').append(temphtml);
var options = $("#checkinbtn0").attr("data-option");
var obj = $.parseJSON(options);

alert(obj.Name);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Just note that, a `jSON object` name need `double quotes`. But if you want to go with your logic, this is your original `string` but with fixed `double quotes`

```js
var Name = 'Alex';
var Age, Gender, HospitalID, Mobile, Address;

var temphtml = `
        <a href="#" id="checkinbtn0" class="btn btn-primary checkinbtn" data-options='{
            "Name":"` + Name + `",
            "Age":"` + Age + `",
            "Gender":"` + Gender + `",
            "HospitalID":"` + HospitalID + `",
            "Mobile":"` + Mobile + `",
            "Address":"` + Address + `"}'>Check in</a>`;
  
  $('#target').append(temphtml);
  var s = $('#checkinbtn0').data('options');
  var str = JSON.stringify(s); // double convert to string
  var obj = $.parseJSON(str);
  alert(obj.Name);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
```